# Images are disappearing after a while of reloading

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, express

I used the mevn tech stack to host a movie blog site on Heroku.
When I submit an image, it initially appears, but if I revisit after an hour or two, the image is gone.

site hosted here:
https://fast-mountain-72029.herokuapp.com/

Api code:

```
    static async createPost(req,res){
        const post = req.body;
        const imagename = req.file.filename;
        post.image = imagename;
        try {
            await Post.create(post);
            res.status(201).json({message: 'Post created sucessfully!'})
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(400).json({message: err.message})
        }
    }
```

Model I use:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    category: String,
    content: String,
    image: String,
    created:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
```

Vue code to display image:

```
<v-img height="250" :src="`/${post.image}`"></v-img>
```

Every time I visit the website, I want the image to show.

Like this:

[image]

more about the project:
https://github.com/shreemahadik8433/MEVN

console window:

[image: console image]

Comment: That question was already asked. What do you see in your console/DOM when the image is not available anymore?

Comment: No resource with given URL is found. I am able to see the file names with image extension . Also I have updated my Question with console image file. (Sorry, I am a little desperate self learner and a noob at using stackoverflow.)

Comment: No, check the "Console" tab for any errors, use "Elements" to inspect the given image and double check in "Network" to see if you can see the image well or not. Double check the CSS too, it is maybe breaking your image somehow. TLDR: try to look a bit more into it + fiddle with it.

Comment: Also, why do you pay for your website on Heroku? Host it on Netlify or Vercel. Also, is `<v-img height="250" :src="`/${post.image}`"></v-img>` a dynamic image? Tried to load it with `require`? I can't see any `vue` in your `package.json` too...

Comment: My git has two branches client and server you saw the server branch. My logic stores the image in a uploads folder. yeah, I know about the Netlify but it was late and I already hosted it on heroku. I will be shifting my project soon to netlify after the error is solved.

Comment: Heroku does not store assets. You'll need to host it somewhere else.

Comment: Damn my doubt was right I will  try to use netlify. thanks for your time sir you helped a lot.

Comment: BTW my assets are stored in mongoDB.

Comment: How are they stored there? URL or base64 data?